# Access token Facebook API Graph - public events

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I have a general quation about the access token for Facebook API Graph.

I'm doing some testing with the API Graph explorer. I want to display some public facebook events on my website. https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=party&type=event
For the testing I created a access token and it's working. 
Now my question: Can I use this token for my website or has it to be renewed all x-days? So when only searching for public events this token is good?

Thanks for your help.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an App Access Token, it is valid forever. It´s just a combination of App ID and App Secret, including a pipe sign: `App-ID|App-Secret`

Careful though, don´t use that token on the client.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

**Edit: I just tested it with an App Token, it seems that you do need a User Token after all. You can use an Extended User Token, it is valid for 60 days.**

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your answer. Big sorry for my delayed feedback!!

I did some testing with api graph explorer. When I select my APP and then select "get user access token" and then submit the search for public events it is working.
But selecting "Get App token" isn't working. There comes:
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,' `

Have you an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: maybe you do need a user token for that call then. i will update my answer, it seems to be the case.